# Winforms add column to a databound datagrid

Tags: winforms, datagrid, datatable

I have a datagrid which is binded to a datatable. Now I wish to add a column to this datagrid. the values are stored in a dictionary.
I wish to add values to columns from this dictionary.
How can I add column with values to either the datagrid or to the datatable?

Answer (score 1):

There are two solution

1. Edit your DataTable and add a field that represent the column you wish to add, then fill it programatically.
2. The second solution is to add a column to the data grid through the designer and then iterate through the data grid cells and fill the values from code-behind.

I personally prefer the first solution, its more clean.

---

To edit you DataTable follow the following steps:

[image: Step One]
[image: Step Two]
[image: Step Three]
[image: Step Four]

Now you can iterate through your DataTable object from code behind and add the values for each row :D

Comment: Thanks, But that is not what I was looking for. I wanted to add the Column, after the table is returned from a select query. Anyways, thanks for the help, my problem is solved now.

Comment: @xaria: No problem, this won't affect your query, your query will fill all the columns but this one, then you can iterate through the rows and fill the last one. Anyways, its good to hear that your problem is solved :), it would be very nice if you posted your answer to share it with the community.